# How gethostbyname() or getnameinfo() work in background?

Tags: c, linux, sockets

**How `gethostbyname()` or `getnameinfo()` work in background?**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <netdb.h>

/* paddr: print the IP address in a standard decimal dotted format */
void
paddr(unsigned char *a)
{
        printf("%d.%d.%d.%d\n", a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3]);
}

main(int argc, char **argv) {
        struct hostent *hp;
        char *host = "google.com";
        int i;

        hp = gethostbyname(host);
        if (!hp) {
                fprintf(stderr, "could not obtain address of %s\n", host);
                return 0;
        }
        for (i=0; hp->h_addr_list[i] != 0; i++)
                paddr((unsigned char*) hp->h_addr_list[i]);
        exit(0);
}
```

output for google.com:

```
74.125.236.198
74.125.236.199
74.125.236.206
74.125.236.201
74.125.236.200
74.125.236.196
74.125.236.193
74.125.236.197
74.125.236.194
74.125.236.195
74.125.236.192
```

output for www.google.com:

```
74.125.236.210
74.125.236.209
74.125.236.212
74.125.236.208
74.125.236.211
```

1. Will the above program do a check in the internet to resolve into IP?
2. Why its showing less IP addresses for **www.google.com** and more for just **google.com**?

Comment: What output did you get? What output did you expect?

Comment: please check the updated question, I want to know the the background process of the above library functions.

Comment: @DragonX It uses [DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) ([visual](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jxYhp0UD5hU) explanation of what gethostbyname() would do). And probably only google know the technical reasons as to why they configured different addresses for google.com and www.google.com

Comment: When you call a function like `gethostbyname`, the library only sends out a request to one or several name servers (your isp's), which may forward the request to another name server (e.g. google's), or may return a cached reply, or something different. What you get to see depends on what the name server returns to the library. Google's nameserver almost certainly does load balancing (i.e. you'll not get the same addresses in the same order every time) and it may do other stuff that isn't immediately obvious to you. Don't bother.

Comment: The rant at http://www.skarnet.org/software/s6-dns/getaddrinfo.html partially addresses your question, and it's interesting anyway XD

Comment: @loreb at skarnet.org/software/s6-dns/getaddrinfo.html it says the  **getaddrinfo() performs NSS resolution, not DNS resolution.** whether NSS resolution includes DNS?

Comment: @DragonX as the rant says, on any **sanely** configured machine, it will basically try /etc/hosts and then use the DNS; the point is that NSS **will practically always** use DNS, but strictly speaking it doesn't **have** to, and it's a complicated mess (see gerrit's answer)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On a Linux system the gethostbyname() call implemented in the glibc performs lookups according to the configuration files **/etc/host.conf** and **/etc/nsswitch.conf**.

Typically in a default configuration it will first look in the **/etc/hosts** file if a local entry for the given name exists and if so, returns that. Otherwise it will proceed with the DNS protocol that is in turn configured by **/etc/resolv.conf** where the nameservers are stated.

Much more complex setups can be configured that lookup LDAP servers, databases etc.

You can also look into some man pages like `man 5 nsswitch.conf`.