# How does socket.gethostbyname work?

Tags: python, sockets, hostname, ipv4

How does the python function `socket.gethostbyname` work?

Specifically, how does python obtain the ipv4 address from the fully qualified domain name?

Comment: CPython is open-source, why don't you check it yourself: [`socketmodule.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/67e1478dba6efe60b8e1890192014b8b06dd6bd9/Modules/socketmodule.c) - `socket_gethostbyname` function, then follow the thread where it takes you as it depends on the underlying platform.

Comment: It gets translated into a gethostbyname system call, which first checks the hosts file and if the name's not found there it queries a DNS server. See  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20284094/how-gethostbyname-or-getnameinfo-work-in-background

Comment: Thanks, that was the information I needed for a related issue - please may you post that as an answer?